# change direction the contents of a layout Without changing " android:supportsRtl "

Tags: android

I'm working on a project that needs to be `false` for `android: supportsRtl`, but for the contents of a RelativeLayout to change the `direction` to `rtl`, how should I do it?

my `Manifest.xml`code :

```xml
 android:supportsRtl="false"
```

and this my layout xml code :

```xml
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:layout_below="@id/calendar_days_name"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/grid_days"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layoutDirection="rtl"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:numColumns="7">
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you check answer below.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `View.setScaleX(-1f)` or `View.setRotationY(180f)` to flip the view horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate that view -

```
yourView.setRotationY(180f)
```

in your case add a id to your parent Relative Layout , and set this.

```
yourRelativeLayout.setRotationY(180f)
```